# how to create form and how send form data to client email id with out using default mail in android

Tags: android

I am building a form that sends emails from an android application, I am using `Intents` to send the email, that is:

```
Intent sendIntent;
sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

My requirement is that I want the email to be sent immediately.

Currently the application is showing me installed email applications in device where I can recompose the email before sending.

I want to send the mail directly without showing installed applications.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: i can help you ping me harun.naik@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

You check this Library its efficient i have used it alot 
https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground